# Prevent Matlab from wrapping phase angles to 0-2pi in complex numbers

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft, phase

I'm dealing with complex numbers in Matlab and I have some problems with their angles.

I have a vector of angles, Ph. Then  I want to construct a vector C of complex numbers as:

```
C=exp(j*Ph).
```

The problem is that Ph contains negative phases because It has odd symmetry so It can be further used to synthesize a signal using a IFFT. This negative phases are wrapped to 0-2pi in the vector C, loosing their odd symmetry.

Is there any way I can prevent Matlab from wrapping the angles?

It might be impossible to do such a thing, because we know that mathematically a phase of -30º is the same as a phase of 330º. But I wonder if wrapping the phases are destroying their desired odd symmetry.

I attach a picture that illustrate my problem, thank you!

[image]

Comment: I don't think the phase wrapping is the issue here - the values you're sending to the ifft function are in rectangular coordinates, so the angle being plotted by phase (which I can't find in the documentation - angle is the normal choice) isn't actually an input to the function. As long as the input is conjugate-symmetric it should be fine, which is true if your real is even- and your imaginary is odd-symmetric. I'm not sure all your descriptions and plots line up right - what you describe doesn't quite match what I see, but I could be misunderstanding something too....

Comment: The real part of C is even-symmetric, and the imaginary part is odd-symmetric, sorry I changed the terms above, it is edited now. I think the problem here is using the "freqz" function. If I get the phase of Y as angle(fft(Y)) I get the same as stored in Ph vector. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Mapping Toolbox, there is a [wrapToPi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/wraptopi.html) function that will do what you want.

Without it, you'll need to implement your own:

```
function [ lambdaWrapped ] = myWrapToPi( lambda )
   lambdaWrapped = lambda - floor(lambda / (2*pi)) * 2*pi;
   lambdaWrapped(lambdaWrapped > pi) = lambdaWrapped(lambdaWrapped > pi) - 2*pi;
end
```

The first line wraps everything from 0-2pi, and the next one takes the values that are greater than pi and moves them to the -pi to 0 range.

```
phase = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
plot(phase);
plot(myWrapToPi(phase));
```

[image: Original plot]
[image: Wrapped plot]

Comment: Thank you Katie, but it doesn't fix my problem. What you suggest is ok if I want to define an odd symmetry between -pi and pi. What I really want is to construct a complex number with odd symmetry in its phase, i.e: phase(k)=-phase(N-k), where N is the number of elements. But it seems to bee imposible, since Matlab wrap any negative phase to 0-2pi

Comment: @JavaRar, I think the end of your comment got cut off. I think you need to expand your question to clarify a bit - I'm not sure where you're getting that 0-2pi plot from at all. The `angle` function to get the phase angle of a complex number wraps -pi to pi.

Comment: Your edited comment just came through. I think wrapping -pi to pi will cause any odd symmetry in the phase to come out like you want, although I'm confused why you need it for anything other than making the symmetry obvious when plotting it or to make a symmetry verification routine. Like you said in your question, -30 degrees and 330 degrees are mathematically identical because you're working with circular units. It shouldn't cause any problems when you do your IFFT. Are you having specific problems that you think are related to the phase wrapping?

Comment: Yes, I have problems woth the IFFT. I'll edit the answer to clarify the whole problem. :)